# Join few tables without repeat same data

Tags: c#, .net, linq, lambda

I have got two tables, 
Feedback Table and Steps Table. Each feedback has multiple Steps. If i use LINQ with join method it returnd same number of step items (obj) in FeedbackViewModel and each contains only 1 single step. I mean ery similar to SQL return.

```
FeedbackViewModel[0]{FeedbackID = 1,FeedbackName="NameA", Steps{Step1}}
FeedbackViewModel[1]{FeedbackID = 1,FeedbackName="NameA", Steps{Step2}}
FeedbackViewModel[2]{FeedbackID = 1,FeedbackName="NameA", Steps{Step3}}
```

BUT I only want one FeedbackViewModel object which contains many Steps.

```
FeedbackViewModel[0]{FeedbackID = 1,FeedbackName="NameA", Steps{Step1, Step2, Step 3 etc..}
```

I can do it by foreach Loop but it doesn't look professional.

Thanks for help

```
public class Feedback 
{
    public int FeedbackID { get; set; }
    public string FeedbackName { get; set; }        
}

public class StepModel
{
    public int StepID { get; set; }
    public int FeedbackID { get; set; } = 0;
    public int StepNumber { get; set; }
    public string StepDetail { get; set; }
    public virtual Feedback FeedBack { get; set; }
}

public class FeedbackViewMODEL
{
    public int FeedbackID { get; set; }
    public string FeedbackName { get; set; }
    public List<StepModel> Steps { get; set; }
}


var quote = from feed in FeedBacks 
           join stp in StePs on feed.FeedbackID equals stp.FeedbackID
           where feed.FeedbackID == id
           select new FeedbackViewMODEL
                    {
                        Step = stp;
                    }
```

Comment: To get rid of duplicate data from `join` , try [group by](https://coderwall.com/p/fsgz6w/using-group-by-linq-c)

Comment: You need to do a group join.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the LINQ group join will combine all the matching steps:

```
var quote = from feed in FeedBacks
            where feed.FeedbackID == id
            join stp in StePs on feed.FeedbackID equals stp.FeedbackID into stpj
            select new FeedbackViewMODEL {
                FeedbackID = feed.FeedbackID,
                FeedbackName = feed.FeedbackName,
                Steps = stpj.ToList()
            };
```

Comment: Thank you NetMage.. It really helped

Answer (score 0):

I think you should left outer join.

from feed in Feedbacks 
        join stp in steps on feed.FeedbackID equal stp.FeedbackID into result
        where feed.FeedBackID == id and result.DefaultIfEmpty()

Comment: I tried but it didn't work but Thank you Santhosh for help.